# Is there a way to acces files in the phone's internal storage without using the Android API file picker?

Tags: android, kotlin, filesystems

I've been stuck on this for almost a whole day now although it seems so trivial. So as a final resort I'll try to ask it here.

For an app I've been working on I want to be able to send binary data files over bluetooth from the android device to a BLE enabled chip. As we want the user to be able to send custom files to the chip we want them to be able to connect the phone to a computer via usb and drag & drop the files from their computer over to the phone just using windows explorer (currently files are stored in the "Documents/BinaryFiles" folder on the phone's internal storage) (apparently this is refered to as 'external' storage).

This approach so far has worked with me using the Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to select the file and load it into memory. Every file however also has an extra associated file in the same folder, I however don't want to open a file picker a 2nd time to select this file, as then the risk exists of the user picking the wrong file and it is just annoying extra effort. The problem is that I really can't seem to find a way to open/load a file into memory without using the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT file picker. Additionaly I want to have some buttons that simply open a file of a certain name into memory without the user having to use any type of filepicker.

Every approach i've attempted so far to acces a file (of any type) in the Documents folder without a file picker just ends up with the app crashing. In the androidManifest.xml I have already added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Functions such as File.listFiles() and File.exists() just return "null" regardless of the presence of files. Attempting to open the file through a Uri such as by converting the path also just leads to the app crashing, for example:

```
var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.fromFile(File("/Documents/BinaryFiles/microscopic.mp3")))
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but this is something extremely basic to do on a regular computer so I don't know why it's giving me so much trouble here within Android.
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't want to spend multiple days being stuck on somthing so seemingly trivial.

Comment: "Every file however also has an extra associated file in the same folder," -- then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and have the user specify the folder. "Functions such as File.listFiles() and File.exists() just return "null" regardless of the presence of files" -- you do not have access rights to arbitrary files, particularly in common shared locations like `Documents`.

Comment: But if I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE how do I then acces the files from there on?

And then how do I gain acces rights for these shared locations?

Comment: "how do I then acces the files from there on?" -- use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to get a `DocumentFile` wrapping the folder. `DocumentFile` then has a `File`-like API to traverse the folder and get at individual documents (themselves represented by a `DocumentFile`). You can then call `getUri()` on a document's `DocumentFile` and pass that to `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` on the content of the document.

Comment: Let the user copy the files from pc to getExternalFilesDir(). Then you can access those files without further user interaction.

Comment: @blackapps It seems however that when using this approach it is not possible to acces this folder through the internal file picker. Even when adding android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and allowing it through an Intent

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tried implementing this however functions. I take the Uri output from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, store it in a global varaible and then in another activity call for DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, global_variable). However when i run listFiles() on this variable it only returns the tree folder name and not the actual folder contents that I can clearly see are there in the file picker.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Indeed. Private storage. You can list the content of such folder.